# Laravel DB: looking for duplicates. Optimize SQL or use Query Builder properly?

Tags: sql, eloquent

I have this code, which works correctly:

```
DB::delete(DB::raw(
"delete
from my_items
where code in (select code
                      from my_items
                      where import_jobs_id = :jobid 
                        and code is not null)
  and code is not null
  and import_jobs_id != :jobid2"), ['jobid' => $job->id, 'jobid2' => $job->id]);
            }
```

I have an import job which inserts data into the my_items table. The import job has its own ID. All rows inserted are marked with this job id.

Rows may have a "code" which should be eventually unique. If they have such a code, after the job is finished, I want to purge duplicates (I get all the codes inserted during this job and I delete the ones that match and do not have the current job ID).

Can I make this more efficient?

Does it make sense to try to rewrite this using Laravel QueryBuilder/Eloquent? "my_items" do have a corresponding Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "self-join" can be used in lieu of a subquery, and if the table is indexed on `code` and `import_jobs_id` columns (each as separate index) then this should be efficient:

```
DB::delete(DB::raw("
    DELETE mi1
    FROM my_items mi1
    JOIN my_items mi2 ON mi1.code = mi2.code
    WHERE mi1.import_jobs_id != :jobid2
    AND mi1.import_jobs_id = :jobid
"), ['jobid' => $job->id, 'jobid2' => $job->id]);

-- Suggested indexes
CREATE INDEX idx_code ON my_items (code);
CREATE INDEX idx_import_jobs_id ON my_items (import_jobs_id);
```

nb: you don't need `AND mi1.code IS NOT NULL` due to the join condition `mi1.code = mi2.code` (as null can never be equal to anything)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a bit rusty with SQL 